# Renumber struct property in array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have struct.

```
structure translation {
    var lineNo: Int
    var language: String
    ....
}
```

then I have an Array of those structs looking like

```
[0] lineNo 0 / lang = English / other vars
[1] lineNo 0 / lang = French / other vars
[2] lineNo 0 / lang = Spanish / other vars
[3] lineNo 1 / lang = English / other vars
[4] lineNo 1 / lang = French / other vars
[5] lineNo 1 / lang = Spanish / other vars
[6] lineNo 3 / lang = English / other vars
[7] lineNo 3 / lang = French / other vars
[8] lineNo 3 / lang = Spanish / other vars
[6] lineNo 4 / lang = English / other vars
[7] lineNo 4 / lang = French / other vars
[8] lineNo 4 / lang = Spanish / other vars
```

I want to renumber the lineNo to get :

```
[0] lineNo 0 / lang = English / other vars
[1] lineNo 0 / lang = French / other vars
[2] lineNo 0 / lang = Spanish / other vars
[3] lineNo 1 / lang = English / other vars
[4] lineNo 1 / lang = French / other vars
[5] lineNo 1 / lang = Spanish / other vars
[6] lineNo 2 / lang = English / other vars
[7] lineNo 2 / lang = French / other vars
[8] lineNo 2 / lang = Spanish / other vars
[9] lineNo 3 / lang = English / other vars
[10] lineNo 3 / lang = French / other vars
[11] lineNo 3 / lang = Spanish / other vars
```

In swift, short of looping through the array, what is the most elegant/effective way to to such a renumber.

Comment: "short of looping through the array" There is no way other than looping through the array. The loop might not look like loop code on the surface, but it will be a loop nonetheless.

Comment: It's not completely clear what your algorithm here is. Do you mean that if there's a skip in `lineNo`, you remove the gap? What if `lineNo` is out of order in the original array? The numbers in brackets are particularly confusing; why do they run 0...8, 6...8? What does your `for` loop look like, and what about it do you not find "elegant/effective?" A complicated `reduce` is not more elegant than a simple `for`; it's just harder for the compiler to optimize. A simple `reduce` that expresses "join values with an operator" is of course a very good thing. Just don't abuse it to replace a loop.

Comment: Assuming you have existing code, and just want opinions on improving it, you may also consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @rob, you're right about the numbers in the bracket, was a copy/paste error. I edited the post to reflect it. Thx also for the tip on codereview, didn't know that. And finally As posted in comments below: I'll go for the loop solution.